# UWP : create a BitmapImage with a google photo api uri/url - (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)

Tags: c#, uwp, uri, bitmapimage, google-photos-api

i am trying to display an image (in an UWP App) from my google photo online storage.([google photos api](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/overview))
When i query the photos i get an json with the following content

```
{
      "id": "APjQy-B1s28LlE3EsrwBQL_bRyrMVpDxHFuu1-vPKwDRS6Ohgl_LzmiaQeFcvul-ZI0BwQMBOK0n-g1c............",
      "productUrl": "https://photos.google.com/lr/photo/APjQy-B1s28LlE3EsrwBQL_bRyrMVpDxHFuu1-vPKwDRS6Ohgl_LzmiaQeFcvul-ZI0B................",
      "baseUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lr/AGiIYOVIHZSM5oJ0HhAm1OzxnYy6A70ZHaDa2bS1wb6IG1Os-b0e3eEtCTKwvqojzeAmhwIRUOxT0-aMiK3VZGIVGKx_F_5rlFrOqUrFBhI62H3ZWlm8nDvOgtkzFO_ZSA103gJA6_-WDtFuRGq8QPWDyCd5Hs4okZ0jHSILkeP_91WF7W_KwSpL7W...................",
      "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
      "mediaMetadata": {
        "creationTime": "........",
        "width": "4000",
        "height": "1844",
        "photo": {
          "cameraMake": "Xiaomi",
          "cameraModel": "Mi 9 Lite",
          "focalLength": 4.74,
          "apertureFNumber": 1.79,
          "isoEquivalent": 1654,
          "exposureTime": "0.050s"
        }
      },
      "filename": "IMG_20200207_191419.jpg"
    },
```

when i past the productUrl in a bowser , i can see the photo. But when i try to create a bitmapimage in the code i get an exception : [The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273307/the-component-cannot-be-found-exception-from-hresult-0x88982f50)
It seems that somehow the image cannot be decoded ?!

Here is my sample code:

```
var uri1 = new Uri("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-600w-1048185397.jpg");
var uri2 = new Uri("https://photos.google.com/lr/photo/APjQy-BpcVPkezt2BLsBmbHfuwHFJ0eIknFMgP8vEGLHVj9n5yBD_aX7-i6E77bA4XYuU-Hyktds4Tut...........");
IRandomAccessStreamReference thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri2);
file = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync("IMG_20200203_215716.jpg", uri2, thumbnail);
    
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
  {
      await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
  }
```

In the sample code you see two uri's. uri1 is working. uri2 throws the exception.
Can someone help me to direct me in the right direction. I do not know where to search.
Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0):

i am going to answer my own question. I should have read the api description more carefully

You should use the baseurl (mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items?hl=en#base-urls)) The product url is a link to the google photo online app.

sample code :

```
  protected override async Task<BitmapImage> GetImageAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var url = $"{item.baseUrl}=w{item.mediaMetadata.width}-h{item.mediaMetadata.height}";
                var uri = new Uri(url);
                IRandomAccessStreamReference sr = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri);

                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

                using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await sr.OpenReadAsync())
                {
                    await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                }
                Width = image.PixelWidth;
                Height = image.PixelHeight;
                return image;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
```